# Azure Devops Release XML variables not being replaced

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to create a release where variables from my library are used to replace values in SetParameters.xml. For replacing I used following task: https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme

In my web.config I have following for my connectionStrings:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="config\connectionStrings.local.config" />
```

For deployment, this should use another file, eg:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="config\connectionStrings.config" />
```

My parameters.xml looks like this:

```
<parameter name="Connection Strings Config File Location"
         defaultValue="__ConnectionStringsConfigurationFileLocation__">
<parameterEntry kind="XmlFile"
                scope="\\Web.config$"
                match="/configuration/connectionStrings/@configSource" />
```

```
<parameter name="Umbraco Database Connection String"
         defaultValue="__UmbracoDatabaseConnectionString__">
<parameterValidation kind="AllowEmpty" />
<parameterEntry kind="XmlFile"
                scope="\\config\\connectionStrings.config$"
                match="/connectionStrings/add[@name='umbracoDbDSN']/@connectionString" />
```

The variable **ConnectionStringsConfigurationFileLocation** is in my library:
[image: 1]

After deploying, the value of the **configSource** in **web.config** remains untouched. But the value of **connectionString** in **\config\connectionStrings.config** is replaced succesfully.
What could be the issue that the web.config is not updating?

**Edit:** Screenshots tasks:

- [replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQKHq.png)
- [deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IJEH.png)

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your script. Could you provide screenshots of the Replace Tokens task and your deployment task so that people can investigate the question further?

Comment: I added screenshots of the tasks.